# Is it ok to imagine having sex weather it’s your partner or someone random

Tags: sin, husband-wife, punishment

Is it ok to imagine having sex weather it’s your partner or someone random

I don’t see my husband all the time as he travels far for work. Before marriage I would imagine having sex with a random person sometimes with someone I know or just random human I imagine. Sometimes it uncontrollable and I can’t stop. I also imagine that the person I’m having sex with is abusive at times.
Please let me know how I can stop this and why it’s bad to do this.

Comment: No it's not haram to imagine, it's just makruh because it can lead you to have desires (which aren't haram too). It's perfectly halal because Allah doesn't judge us on thoughts, he judges us on your beliefs and actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to abstine from this, but if you can't control it then it is normal and we are human beings with needs and the prophet [pbuh] said

> Allah forgives my followers those (evil deeds) their souls may whisper or suggest to them as long as they do not act (on it) or speak.

Other then that i think you should talk to your husband about it because it is his religious duty to satisfy you with your sexual needs. After all Allah [swt] said in the holy book

> It is made lawful for you, in the nights of fasts, to have sex with your women. They are apparel for you, and you are apparel for them...
> Quran 2:187